# Create Blog with Python

Tags: python, asp.net

I want create blog with python,With the creation of the link the problem appears:
[does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.]

urls.py-Post

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from . import views
app_name='Post'

urlpattern = [
      url(r'^$', views.all_posts, name='all_posts'),
      url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)$', views.post, name='post')
              ]
```

urls.py-blog

```
from django.conf.urls import  include, url
from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns = [
      url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url('blog/' , include('Post.urls', namespace='blog'))
       ]
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .models import Post

def all_posts(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'all_posts.html')




def post(request, id):
    pass
```

models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


# user - title - img - content - Created

class Post(models.Model) :
    user = models.ForeignKey(User )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(default=' ')
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'post_img/')
    Created = models.DateTimeField()


   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

i need help , thanks

Comment: It will be helpful if you add what version of Django you are using. Also give full stacktrace if possible.

Comment: Django==1.11.18
Pillow==5.4.1
pytz==2018.9

Answer (score 0):

Now you can create a blog using Python as well as Django code. If you are familiar with these languages, you can easily create a blog using these languages. Get detailed information about it at https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-blog-using-python-as-well-as-django/